# Inaccurate diagonal lines on slower SetDefaultMouseSpeed

Tags: autohotkey

I have an AHK script that converts vector files to Mousemoves and Clicks. 
**SVG source file example:**

[image: source file]

The next image is the output I get on MS PaintBrush when I run the SVG of the previous picture on my script with a **regular mouse speed:**

[image: hi speed]

As we can notice on the cyan lines, it looks ok. Now (on the next picture's pink lines) the problem I'm facing. **This is the output I get on MS PaintBrush if I change `SetDefaultMouseSpeed` to 100:**

[image: low speed]

I need to reduce the mouse speed to make it work on lagged online applications, but the lines become crooked. To workaround this issue, I'm currently using `SetMouseDelay` instead. My question is: **Is there a way to use higher `SetDefaultMouseSpeed` values without to get these crooked diagonals lines?**

Here's a minimal code with the issue:

```
SendMode Event  

$F1::
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 2
SetMouseDelay, 10   

Mousemove, 159, 180
Send {Click Down}
Mousemove, 188, 168
Mousemove, 217, 159
Mousemove, 249, 155
Send {Click Up}

return

$F2::
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 100
SetMouseDelay, 10   

Mousemove, 159, 180
Send {Click Down}
Mousemove, 188, 168
Mousemove, 217, 159
Mousemove, 249, 155
Send {Click Up}

return
```

This is the minimal example's result on MS PaintBrush (with zoomed version on the right side):

[image: minimal example output]

*The smooth black line is result of the F1 keypress (default mouse speed) and the crooked pink line is result of the F2 keypress (reduced speed).*

Comment: The problem here is the assumption of how AHK moves the mouse. The mouse is merely being moved from its origin to its destination. Nothing in the provided code mandates a smooth curve at a higher speed or the lower speed; This is just how AHK works. If you want to add smoothness at higher speeds, then you'll likely have to add many more points in the code to account for AHK's behavior. But you may still encounter errata because the behavior is simply not meant for these smooth arcs.

Comment: It will likely be easier to just automate a program that already has the ability to rasterize an SVG file, or use a language like Python.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that the UI your script is interacting with is not responsive enough. In that case there is not much you can do. I mean besides closing background processes or upgrading your hardware.
You might wanna try to use [ControlClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm) instead of MouseMove etc. This way you could just make it happen in the background, so that you can at least do other stuff while it's drawing.

Another thing you could try would be to only use [Click](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm) and sending a click for every pixel you want to set. You might have to do some basic interpolation math for that, though.

And then there is [PixelSetColor](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelGetColor.htm), which you could use to determine if the pixel has actually been drawn.

But in the end you are probably better off searching for a simple converter tool/library. I mean at the end of the day you are just converting an SVG into a bitmap.

My advise:
Get ImageMagick, then you can simply run: `Run, magick convert test.svg test.png` from your ahk script or type `magick convert test.svg test.png` into the commandline. I think Inkscape has similar commands to do stuff like that.

Edit: 
You could try to send mouse click/move events using PostMessage. The behavior is very similar to ControlClick, but you can also do mouse move this way.
E.g.

```
x := 159
y := 189

;WM_LBUTTONDOWN
PostMessage, 0x201, 0, x&0xFFFF | y<<16,, YourWinTitle


x := 188
y := 168

;WM_MOUSEMOVE
PostMessage, 0x200, 0, x&0xFFFF | y<<16,, YourWinTitle

x := 217
y := 159

;WM_MOUSEMOVE
PostMessage, 0x200, 0, x&0xFFFF | y<<16,, YourWinTitle

x := 249
y := 155

;WM_MOUSEMOVE
PostMessage, 0x200, 0, x&0xFFFF | y<<16,, YourWinTitle


;WM_LBUTTONUP
PostMessage, 0x202, 0, x&0xFFFF | y<<16,, YourWinTitle
```

Another thing you should totally try is using `SetBatchLines -1`. Just put it in the beginning of your script. This should speed your script up.

Comment: About the UI, I did try the script to draw in different applications and the result is always the same, regardless of the current UI. About the ControlClick (runs in background) I'm aware about it but unfortunately AutoHotKey don't have a feature that does MOVES on background (only clicks). Then, if I do a click on every pixel, it would work in background but it would be extremely slow (I did try). It is not an image converter: my script is able to draw in websites such as anondraw.com while ImageMagick would not work in such kind of application.

Comment: Added some more ideas to my answer.

Comment: 1- Thanks for the ideas and I'm sorry about an error I found just right now in the example given: I wrote `SendMode Input` while it should be `SendMode Event` (its fixed now). 2- I am trying to use your PostMessage code but it isn't working, I'll keep trying and if I get any result I'll give you the feedback.

Comment: You mean `Click Down` instead of `Send {Click Down}` ? Yes but the issue still the same;

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea. You mentioned that you want to send the mouse events to a website. So it might be way faster and more reliable to trigger the mouse events on the website itself using the dev tools of your browser.
You mentioned anondraw.com so I gave that a try and it seems to works.

- Go to the website in your browser
- Press F12 to open the developer tools
- Click on the console tab in the developer tools
- Now paste the following code into it and press enter

Load some libraries:

```
//This first part is not necessary in this case because the website already uses jquery
//var script = document.createElement('script');
//script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
//document.head.appendChild(script); 

//Load some scripts to make simulating mouse events easy
$.getScript('http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.js')
$.getScript('http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.ext.js')
$.getScript('http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/bililiteRange.js')
$.getScript('http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.key-sequence.js')
$.getScript('http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.key-combo.js')
$.getScript('http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.drag-n-drop.js')
```

Now copy paste the following code and press enter:

```
//Simulate mouse events to draw stuff
$('.paint-canvas').simulate("mousedown", {clientX: 188, clientY: 168});
$('.paint-canvas').simulate("mousemove", {clientX: 188, clientY: 168});
$('.paint-canvas').simulate("mousemove", {clientX: 217, clientY: 159});
$('.paint-canvas').simulate("mousemove", {clientX: 249, clientY: 155});
$('.paint-canvas').simulate("mouseup", {clientX: 249, clientY: 155});

// (paint-canvas is the class name of the element in which you want to draw)
```

Comment: Hey I'm trying this just right now but [**I get an error**](https://i.gyazo.com/f1cd485eefc8e272ef0f4f0f1430f913.png) (and nothing happens in the canvas). Since the error mentions 'cross-origin' I think thats because the scripts are located in a different domain (not in anondraw server).

Comment: Execute it in two steps. First run all the $.getScript lines. Then run the rest. And make sure you have selected the drawing tool on the website.

Comment: I do still get the error; I have tried on both Chrome and Firefox; I also tried to paste it line by line, but got the same error again "Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin 'anondraw.com' from accessing a cross-origin frame".

Comment: I tried it in Chromium and Firefox. Works just fine for me. No errors. And my browsers are up2date. Are you using any addons that could cause this? Just to clarify, I went to http://anondraw.com/collab#private_mv0sm,0,0 closed the popup message, changed to the brush tool, pasted the $.getScript lines, pressed enter, pasted the rest of the code, pressed enter. => Line was drawn.

Comment: Yes I did exactly the same, but I get error messages after press Enter plus I dont have anything drawn on canvas. Im on Windows 10 Chrome 58.0.3029.110

Comment: About the addons, the only I had adblock I did turn it off, but the result is the same;